# Django Rest Framework Tokens Are Not Being Automatically Generated

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework, token

I am (trying) to use Django Rest Framework's Token-based authentication. I have the following in my app's **models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.conf import settings

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Whenever I create a new account (either through 'createsuperuser' or by using my registration form), the user is correctly added to the 'auth_user' table. However, although the 'authtoken_token' table is created, there is nothing added to it. This leads me to believe that my @reciever may not be working properly.

I can however manually create tokens using the Django shell. Those tokens will be properly added to the authtoken_token table.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Do you have AUTH_USER_MODEL defined explicitly in `settings.py`? Otherwise, you could always use `get_user_model()`

Comment: I do not have it explicitly defined. I have just now tried using get_user_model() however I am presented with the same result.

Comment: Do you have logging configured? Try to either print or log something in the receiver and see if it's even running.

Comment: No I do not have logging configured. I will set that up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to check:

- Is the receiver even running? Add a print or log inside to check that it is called in the first place
- If `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is not defined, you may need to use `get_user_model()` instead
- Make sure that this code is inside the `models.py` file of an app that is in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`

I've used DRF for several years and never had this problem. One of the above is likely your culprit.

Comment: What is the best way to add a print? I have used get_user_model() and I am sure that app is in settings.INSTALLED_APPS so my guess would be the receiver is not loading

Comment: ... `print "Hello World"`

Comment: Huh. Figured it was a lot more involved than that. Will this simply print to the Django console?

Comment: It will if the receiver is running! Did you check the point about the code being in `models.py`?

Comment: I am now getting this error: "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet."

Comment: Can you post your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Nevermind found a work-around. Seems to be working perfectly now. Thanks a bunch